# Take user input and put it in a list of characters (Python 3)

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

I'm looking for a simple way of taking input from the user and placing it into a list of single character elements.

For example:

- Input: word2

  ```
  List = ['w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '2']
  ```

Comment: Very Easy, List = list(input('Input string: '))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`input`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) to take input:

```
>>> word = input()
word2   <--- user type this.
>>> word
'word2'
```

Use [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list) to conver a string into a list containg each character.

```
>>> list(word)
['w', 'o', 'r', 'd', '2']
```

This works because `list` accepts any iterable and string objects is iterable; Iterating a string yield each character.

Comment: Thanks, the only issue was that I had to change my variables called "list" to something else.